# display a string in the form of an email address entered into a TextField in a drop-down list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Using TypeScript, React, MUI, ReactHookForm, and Yup in an email format in a TextField. We would like to create a system that displays a drop-down list of strings entered in a TextField in the form of an email and allows the user to make a selection.

[State while inputting data into TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Dng.png)

[If the string being entered is determined to be an e-mail, a drop-down list will appear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnAGN.png)

[Click on the drop-down list to see the "Accessible Users" list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEEdu.png)

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-user-dialog-rs007e?file=/src/InvitationButton.tsx:0-485)

Comment: You can use [Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.